# How to get parameters from stored procedures in a textbox in C # occupying ODBC?

Tags: c#, odbc

I am doing some ODBC connection tests, I want the parameters that I have in the Stored procedures to appear in my Textboxes, I already have my ODBC connection in a separate class and this is my code, I am new to programming

```
class conexion
{
    string Cadena = "DSN=PruebaODBC1";
    public OdbcConnection conectar = new OdbcConnection();
    
    public conexion()
    {
     
        conectar.ConnectionString = Cadena;
    
    }

    public void Abrir()
    {
        try
        {
            conectar.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Conexion Abierta");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error al conectarse"+ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public void cerrar()
    {
        conectar.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Write your question in english, please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English

Comment: ok i changed the language

Comment: @AncelmoLuna Your question is still unclear and very broad. " I want the parameters that I have in the Stored procedures to appear in my Textboxes" what textboxes? And where is the code to do that, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better tell us where parameters are located.
This code before opening the connection.
Providing objTextBox - the textbox needed (should be from your source known)

```
       string theText = objTextBox.Text;
       int parValue = 0;
       try
        {
            int parValue = Int32.Parse(theText );
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unable to parse '{theText}'");
        }
       string commandText = "SELECT * FROM STAFF WHERE peopleId = @Id";
       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            commandText, connection);
       if (parValue > 0)   

       {
           command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
           command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = parValue;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

the parameters are from the sql stored procedures, in this case I am using ODBC and I want my parameters to appear in my textbox, I leave the examples of my stored procedure

```
USE [PRUEBAX]
GO
******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_Agregar]
@Id_Num numeric,
@Nombre varchar(50),
@Valor numeric,
@Tipo varchar (50),
@Descripcion varchar (50)
as
begin
insert into DATOSOPC values
(@Id_Num, @Nombre, @Valor, @Tipo, @Descripcion)
end



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(Cadena))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SP_Agregar", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", textBox1.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor", textBox2.ToString());

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Num 4", SqlDbType.Int);

                    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
                        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(row[""]);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message.ToString(), "Error");
                return;
            }
```